# Visual overflow on overflow hidden property

Tags: html, css, overflow

I already set overflow property on html tag hidden but if height of html box is let say 200px I can see the overflow of its content clearly . why?

```css
html {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the result
[image: Output-image]

Comment: Why are you putting the ***restraining*** CSS rules on the HTML tag rather than the `p` tag? If you swap your overflow rule to your `p` tag it will work as you intend.

Comment: html has no parent and cant overflow. The height of html is always calculated to fit content.

Comment: I actually trying to see what is under  this html tag canvas. I think you may understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach.  Body should be styled as well. Add `body` after `html`;

It is not a good idea to change body and html for this work, but that is possible. Creating a `div` element is a better option.

```css
html,body{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i really had a hard time deciding if I upvote this or not. The solution to add the overflow and height to the body is correct. However you could have removed the html selector comepletely as it has no effect in the first place. Also you are incorrect that it is not a good idea to change html and body. There enough reasons why this is possible. THat is possible because there just as many reasons that you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the code into DIV, somthing like this:

```css
div {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <p> Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
        Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  LLots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  Lots Of Text  L
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually trying to see what is under  this html tag canvas. I think you may understand.